# Denotational semantics of IMP While

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I know that the denotational semantics of the IMP while loop is the least fixed point of $\mathcal{F}:(State \rightharpoondown State) \rightarrow (State \rightharpoondown State)$, written as: $[\![ while(b) \quad s]\!] = fix(\mathcal{F})$, where $fix$ is the least fixed-point. And that the fixed-points of $\mathcal{F}$ are elements $(State \rightharpoondown  State)$. But how do I know that it's the least-fixed point? And how would I describe all the fixed points of $\mathcal{F}$ associated to the IMP while loop?

Comment: What version of IMP are you using?

Comment: @MarkSaving The most recent, I believe.

Comment: I mean, what is the source material for IMP? Are you referring to the language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMP_(programming_language)? Or are you referring to a toy language in a book on programming language theory?